# Logging a react function to the console renders twice in my console

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, console, console.log

Whenever I console log any function in my react app, I'm always seeing the same render twice though it doesn't affect my code but it does this different from every other person own.

Comment: Because you are in the  [React Strict Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) , the function would excute twice to ensure your function components is pure

Answer (score 0):

In your index.js file, if the App is wrapped with React.StrictMode, it will render twice. The purpose is to catch bugs that might occur.
Example

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```